# Emit and connect a signal from another application

Tags: python, qt, pyside, signals-slots

I'm using PySide.
Is it possible to emit a custom signal from say application1 and have another application2 that can connect to this signal and run a method within application2.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: If you're talking Qt signals/slots: no, that won't work. You need a proper IPC mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this with pySide but if the applications have been started from a common point, (one of them or a common launcher), then given the applications process handle, (PID), then you should be able to raise an event on it from another application - a bit like call backs.